# object-key value array in *ngFor for angular 7

Tags: angular, object

I need to set object array value in a table but the result is not reflecting.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let file of err_data ">
    <tr>
      <td>{{file.details.commodity_name}}</td>
      <td>{{file.row}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let error of file.errors | keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let error_type of error[key]  | keyvalue">
            {{ error_type}}
        </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

[Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9zD5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't required <div *ngFor="let error_type of error[key]  | keyvalue">

have a look below code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let file of err_data ">
   <tr>
     <td>{{file.details.commodity_name}}</td>
     <td>{{file.row}}</td>
     <td *ngFor="let error of file.errors | keyvalue">
       {{error.key}} --- {{error.value[0]}}
     </td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @Arjun Nair thanks for verifying the my answer. Please do upvote too. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
Your key value is undefined, your file.errors is an object which can't be iterated through *ngFor.
```

If the object format is always standard you can do

```
 <td *ngFor="let error of file.errors | keyvalue">
            <div *ngFor="let error_type of error  | keyvalue">
                {{ error_type.tax}}  {{error_type.unit}}
            </div>
          </td>
```